# Inspection of long condition bodies using Intellij Idea

Tags: java, regex, if-statement, intellij-idea, conditional-statements

I want to find and re-factor code snippets like this:

```
@Override
public void init() {
    if (!initialized) {
        super.init();
        setSizeFull();
        initLayout();
        initTable();
        initButtons();
        initialized = true;
    }
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void init() {
    if (initialized) {
        return;
    }
    super.init();
    setSizeFull();
    initLayout();
    initTable();
    initButtons();
    initialized = true;
}
```

I couldn't find any way to find all snippets like this in my code. I've tried regular expression but I could not write a valid regular expression to find them.
If there is any solution I would like to hear it.
Thanks...

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to make this change? Does other snippets have the same `initialized` variable?

Comment: It's just an example. There are many if statements that has no else and second form is better. You can check [1](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement) or [2](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Computer_Programming/Coding_Style/Minimize_nesting)

Answer (score 0):

You can use structural search and replace (Edit | Find | Replace Structurally) to find and refactor such code fragments.